# How to read a message from a bot via telegram API?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a room with a couple of bots, one of them needs to read all the messages on the room including other bot's messages.

Telegram API says bots can't see other bots message otherwise they might get caught in a "loop".

Since i really need to work around this i'm wondering if there is a known workaround?

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be any workaround using the Bot APIs since the messages in **getUpdates** or **webhook** of the Bot will be from Users alone.

One workaround could be to use the [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) and create a normal user as a Bot.

Comment: On the documentation they justify it by saying "bots talking to bots wouldn't be a good idea", but my bot doesn't need to reply to bot messaes. Instead it only filters messages from bots and then broadcast the important ones to users who subscribed to it. I would love to avoid having to deal with telegram-cli just for that hook.

Comment: As @kroe said, Bots can't read other Bots messages, and i've tested it again right now to be sure. Instead you can use telegram-cli(https://github.com/vysheng/tg) and receive messages as json through cli.

Comment: @VahidMsm i would be curious to know how to setup tg to send JSON to an http every time a message come, like a "client ~> webhook" sort of link. but for now i end up sorting out my system in a different way cause i didn't have enough time to work around this very boring limitation from Telegram Bot API.